# set "\x3b" as a delimiter

Tags: awk, delimiter

I have a file including genes in the following format. I want to process the file and make each row show one gene (separate the multiple genes in one line into multiple lines).

```
C10orf32
C10orf32,C10orf32-ASMT
C19orf33\x3bYIF1B
C19orf73,LIN7B
C19orf73,PPFIA3\x3bLIN7B
```

I used the following command and want to set "," and "\x3b" as delimiters, but "\x3b" is still in the outfile, as show below

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=",|\x3b";} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
C10orf32
C10orf32
C10orf32-ASMT
C19orf33\x3bYIF1B
C19orf73
LIN7B
C19orf73
PPFIA3\x3bLIN7B
```

but I want

```
C10orf32
C10orf32
C10orf32-ASMT
C19orf33
YIF1B
C19orf73
LIN7B
C19orf73
PPFIA3
LIN7B
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\x3b` is an escape code; Awk treats it as the character [semicolon](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b/index.htm).  If you want the literal string backslash, letter x, digit 3, letter b, you need to double the backslash, to escape it.

Comment: Thank you. I doubled the \\ with the following command, but it does not work  awk 'BEGIN {FS=",|\\x3b";} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' file.txt

Comment: I also tried the gawk but it does not work either.

Comment: how \x3b comes, why it not shown as semicolon? How can I change \x3b into semicolon?

Comment: Your sample data does not seem to contain a literal semicolon. Not really sure which part of your question to start guessing about if what you posted isn't correct.

Comment: Anyway, `sed 's/,\|\\x3b/\n/g' file.txt` seems like a more straightforward way to approach your problem (assuming your `sed` understands `\n` to mean a literal newline in the substitution string).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=",|\\\\x3b"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' file.txt
```

This works.
I don't know exactly why though, just many a time double the backslash again will work...